# How to show and hide an object for different animations

Tags: animation, keyframes, layers, visibility

Is it possible to show and hide an object on different animation strips? I have an Attack strip for my character where he's holding a gun. However, I don't want this object to show in his idle, jump and walk animations. I've tried keyframing the Restrict Viewport Visibility for the gun object, but I can't get this method to work throughout the different strips; only the one. I saw a video where you can keyframe the layers, but when I tried it, it didn't work. It says the layers property can't be animated. :-\

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the Attack Action has the character with his gun, but in the Idle Action, he's holding it as well. How could I remove it from the other animation strips? I did try just having a separate save with only the Attack animation, but that's a problem and not very practical when importing into Unity. Because otherwise I'll have one model with the other three animations, and one with just the one. It's a bit of a pain having to switch between two models.

Comment: Can anyone help? Is it possible?

Comment: What about Keyframing the material for the Gun so it can be Transparent?

Comment: Could try that. I guess that would need to be keyframed via the Node Editor? Apart from that, is there no other way? Thanks.

Comment: Not done character animation, but in other Blender animations I keyframe objects out of view via a Location keyframe, making the translation so quick it takes only a single frame.

Comment: I don’t think that will work for me though as I import my character and animations into Unity, so I think it’ll still show. This is where I wish I could still keyframe selected/unselected layers.

Comment: Also, if I make the material Transparent, that's only going to work in rendered mode, right? In Object Mode, and when I import everything into Unity, it's still going to show?

Comment: @DustyShinigami I've used rob 's method frequently in another animator and of course Blender and it works fine.  If the weapon is parented to the hand or whatever, you'd have to keep it miles away and out of sight. It's relative position to the hand can always be re-keyframed if it can be seen later along the timeline.  It's a workaround obviously but as you're getting a little desperate...

Comment: I'm afraid for my purposes, it's not going to work. :( I have 4 animations, and I'd have to set the LocRotScale for the gun on the Action strip to set its place, but that means if I move it out the way in the other strips and set the LocRotScale, it'll be in that position when I go back to the Action strip.

Comment: I refrained from suggesting this last time as it can get messy, but what if you did the swaps with the character instead?  Hang the expense and have two!  One with the gun and one without?  You keep one out of sight and swap them location-wise?  The swap is done in Untity of course so I would have thought you wouldn't have to worry about scale etc,once both are in Unity?  Just move the one you don't want out of sight until it's required.  - another thought - scale the gun down (in Unity) to almost zero so it can't be seen  and bring it back up to size when it's needed with a keyframe?

Comment: Turns out there's a much simpler solution within Unity that I discovered. The gun object could be imported as its own object, parented to the character's rig in the hierarchy, accessed with the Attack animation in the Animator tab, and then you can select the object's properties including an option to enable/disable whether it can be seen. This way, it can be disabled within the other animations. :)